# Nodejs Stream chaining promises write only the first one

Tags: node.js, csv, promise, stream

i'm trying to make a Stream that is writing to multiples files using an async Generator.

Using reduce promises are executed sequentially so the desired output is :

```
$ wc -l *
42 f1.csv
98 f2.csv
78 f3.csv
```

but i'm getting the following result :

```
$ wc -l *
42 f1.csv // only the first one is good
0  f2.csv // nothing in
0  f3.csv // same
```

AsyncGenerator() is a ElasticSearch Scroll Search ([Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/scroll_examples.html))
I send him different query on each promise.

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

async function* Query(params) {

    var response = await ESClient.search(params);

    while (true) {
        const sourceHits = response.hits.hits;

        if (sourceHits.length === 0) {
            break;
        }

        for (const hit of sourceHits) {
            yield hit;
        }

        if (!response._scroll_id) {
            break;
        }

        response = await ESClient.scroll({
            scrollId: response._scroll_id,
            scroll: params.scroll
        });
    }
}

async function* AsyncGenerator() {

        const params = {
            index: 'apache-logs',
            scroll: '5s',
            _source: ["foo"],
            size: 2048,
            body: { query } // ElasticSearch DSL Query
        };

        for await (const res of Query(params)) {
            yield res;
        }
    }

async function WriteToFile(file) {

        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const input = Readable.from(AsyncGenerator());
            const output = fs.createWriteStream(file + '.csv');

            await pipeline(
                input,
                json2csv,
                output
            );
            resolve();   
        });
}

const lists = ["f1", "f2", "f3"];

const last = lists.reduce(async (previous, next) => {
            await previous;
            return WriteToFile(next);
}, Promise.resolve());

last.then(_ => { 
    console.log("DONE");  
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

(Lorem ipsum lalalaalalal (sry stackoverflow is asking to provide more details but i dont have lol))

Comment: Might be useful to have in your code's question all requires of your code (Readable, AsyncGenerator and pipeline)

Comment: sry, edited. The AsyncGenerator is a simple generator ( yield { foo: "bar" }; ...).

Comment: Can we have the full code for AsyncGenerator ? I think you need to restart your generator between the WriteToFile.

Comment: Edited. The asyncGenerator works well, if i  console.log the response in the while(true) i got it,  but after the console.log("DONE") in last.then(). So the stream is closed before i write the response to the file?

Comment: Can you try replacing the reduce by a simple for loop with await ? See if it is the reduce the issue or the others functions.

Comment: tried with `for(let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        await WriteToFile(lists[i]);
    }` same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure because my acquaintances are poor in NodeJs. I think you are only calling one time to the function which is creating your .csv

```html
const lists = ["f1", "f2", "f3"];

const last = lists.reduce(async (previous, next) => {
            await previous;
            return WriteToFile(next);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Hi, no :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce